# Can't change an instance of view controller's property

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

> I have this button in my first view controller, when you press it, it
>   triggers 2 action:
>
> - a function `iterateItems`
> - a segue which animates to `ResultViewController`

I need to set `dataSource` of `ResultViewController` to `bestComposition` in order to complete its view, and the value of this property can only be obtained after `iterateItems` is finished, I put this code in `iterateItems`:

```
print(bestComposition.count)
let resultVC = ResultViewController()
resultVC.dataSource = bestComposition
```

However, in the `viewDidAppear` method of `ResultViewController`, value of `dataSource` is not changed, here's the `ResultViewController`:

```
var dataSource = [WeaponItems]()
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print(dataSource.count)
    ...
}
```

The value of `dataSource` is 3 in `ViewController`, but is always 0 in `ResultViewController`, why doesn't it change?

**Edit (Code for prepare for segue):**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let secondVC = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
    secondVC.transitioningDelegate = self
    secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
}
```

Comment: How are you performing segue? Show your `prepareForSegue` method too.

Comment: @Mr.UB I added the code

Comment: show prepare for segue method too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resultVC` is AN instance of ResultViewController, newly created by this line:

```
let resultVC = ResultViewController()
```

It's not THE instance that is created automatically as part of the segue.  `resultVC` is never displayed, so it's `viewDidAppear` never runs, and so the print statement is never executed.  Meanwhile, the instance created by the segue is presented, so it's `viewDidAppear` does run - but the value for its `dataSource` is unchanged.  Try:

```
let resultVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ResultViewController
```

Comment: I can't do it this way, the `resultVC` is created in another class

Comment: @BrightFuture How is the class with `bestComposition` related to the class where the segue occurs?

Comment: The `iterateItems` is from that class called `Calculator`, I created an instance of `Calculator` in the `ViewController` (where the segue occurs)

Comment: Can you add the code to your question?  Is the segue linked directly to the button, or triggered by `performSegueWithIdentifier` in code?

Comment: It's triggered directly to the button - I set the segue in storyboard then override it. The code of `iterateItems` is a bit long to add.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let secondVC = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
    secondVC.transitioningDelegate = self
    secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    secondVC.dataSource = bestComposition
}
```